# C program to read from hex file giving unexpected output

Tags: c

How come this program does not read a hex file correctly?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *buffer;
unsigned int fileLen;
void ReadFile(char *name);


void ReadFile(char *name)
{
        FILE *file;

        file = fopen(name, "rb");
        if (!file)
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file %s", name);
                return;
        }

        //Getting file length
        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
        fileLen=ftell(file);
        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

        //Allocating memory
        buffer=(char *)malloc(fileLen+1);
        if (!buffer)
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "Mem error!");
                                fclose(file);
                return;
        }

        fread(buffer, fileLen, 1, file);
        fclose(file);


}

int main()
{
   var32 code;
   char filename[20];
   printf("Enter the file name: ");
   scanf("%s", &filename);
   ReadFile(filename);
   printf("FIle contents: %x\n",buffer);

}
```

If i print a huge hex file, it just prints 5 to 6 digits.

Comment: You have a potential bug with the filename array... what if the user enters a filename greater than 20 characters?

Comment: could you provide the whole code? b.e I can't see, where ur declaring buffer..

Comment: Does it work correctly without the scanf? filename is already a pointer as the argument..

Comment: What are `buffer` and `fileLen` defined as and why don't we see that in the code?

Comment: They are global, so i missed out. Will add it

Comment: It works correctly with scanf with normal files

Comment: @kingsmasher1 Any particular reason why they are global?

Comment: @MrLister: Yes, because they are used by some other functions too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
printf("FIle contents: %x\n",buffer);
```

"%x" just prints ONE hex value. It is printing the memory address of your buffer, not its contents.

Try changing:

```
    fread(buffer, fileLen, 1, file);
    fclose(file);
```

adding afterwards:

```
    ...
    fclose(file);
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < fileLen; i++)
        printf("%02x ", buffer[i];
```

This will print the whole binary content. But it's not necessary to read the whole file to do this, you can output blocks of, say, 1 K at a time...

**A different implementation**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE     4096
int main(void)
{
     uint8_t  *buffer;  // Explicit 8 bit unsigned, but should equal "unsigned char"
     FILE     *file;
     char     filename[512];
     // We could also have used buffer[BUFFER_SIZE], but this shows memory alloc
     if (NULL == (buffer = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE)))
     {
          fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n");
          return -1;
     }
     printf("Enter the file name: ");
     // Read a line terminated by LF. Max filename size is MAXPATH, or 512
     fgets(filename, 512, stdin);
     // Trim filename (Windows: CHECK we don't get \r instead of \n!)
     {
         // Being inside a { }, crlf won't be visible outside, which is good.
         char     *crlf;
         if (NULL != (crlf = strchr(filename, '\n')))
              *crlf = 0x0;
     }
     if (NULL == (file = fopen(filename, "rb")))
     {
         fprintf(stderr, "File not found: '%s'\n", filename);
         return -1;
     }
     while(!feof(file) && !ferror(file))
     {
          size_t i, n;
          if (0 == (n = (size_t)fread(buffer, sizeof(uint8_t), BUFFER_SIZE, file)))
               if (ferror(file))
                    fprintf(stderr, "Error reading from %s\n", filename);
                    // Here, n = 0, so we don't need to break: next i-cycle won't run
          for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
          {
               printf("%02x ", buffer[i]);
               if (15 == (i % 16))
                    printf("\n"); // Every 16th byte, a newline
          }
     }
     fclose(file); // file = NULL; // This ensures file won't be useable after fclose
     free(buffer); // buffer = NULL; // This ensures buffer won't be useable after free
     printf("\n");
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Didn't understand. What do i need to change `fread(buffer, fileLen, 1, file);` these 2 statements with?

Comment: You need to add those three lines (size_t i, etc.) after fclose(file), in order to output the file's contents.

Comment: `printf("%02x ", buffer[i])` it prints digits correctly, but the hex as suppose "b2" as "fffffb2" also double zeros as separated ones.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Declare buffer as "unsigned char", not char. Just for the lulz, I'll also add a different code sample.

Answer (score 4):

The `printf()` statement will print the address of `buffer`, in hexadecimal format. You need to `printf()` each byte in `buffer` (<strike>and you must null terminate `buffer` so the caller knows when to stop or return the number of bytes in `buffer` to the caller</strike>) and ensure caller knows how many bytes are in `buffer` (null termination is not safe as reading in binary).

Also:

- ensure `buffer` is not null before dereferencing (which is required to print byte-by-byte)
- check the return value of `fread()` to ensure it was successful
- remember to `free()` buffer when no longer required
- cast of return value of `malloc()` unrequired (see [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc))
- restrict the number of bytes read by `scanf()` to avoid buffer overrun: `scanf("%19s", filename);`
- `code` is an unused local variable

Answer (score -1):

If with hex you mean binary, you can't print those directly, the output will end at the first zero byte in the file.

Also, if the file cannot be found, you say "Unable to open file" first and then continue with saying "File contents: ..."

And as the others point out, you are printing the buffer the wrong way.

And you don't free the buffer.